# How to use clang for windows using mingw headers/libs

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, mingw, clang

I downloaded the clang for windows binary package from [the website](http://llvm.org/releases/download.html).  It provides some nice VS/MSBuild integration by allowing to build VS projects using clang instead of MSVC.  However, I notice that it still uses the MSVC C Library and also the MSVC linker (link.exe).  Also, including any C++ STL headers like string or iostream causes build errors.

My question is: Is it possible to use full clang/llvm toolchain along with some non-Microsoft libraries (like [libc++](http://libcxx.llvm.org/), [mingw](http://mingw.org/) etc.) to build a native Windows binary?  Doing all of this from within VS is a bonus but even from command-line would be fine.

Comment: I guess [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39871656/how-to-use-clang-with-mingw-w64-headers-on-windows/47148323#47148323) answers your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use clang with mingw-w64 headers on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39871656/how-to-use-clang-with-mingw-w64-headers-on-windows)